# Fetching YouTube search results through HTTP connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube, urllib2, urllib

I have been using the following function in order to fetch YouTube search results:

```
from urllib  import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen

def fetch(search_query):
    url = 'http://www.youtube.com/results?'
    args = urlencode({'search_query':search_query})
    conn = urlopen(url,args)
    data = conn.read()
    conn.close()
    return data
```

---

Recently it started to return "empty results" in some cases, forcing me to change my code:

```
from urllib  import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen

def fetch(search_query):
    url = 'http://www.youtube.com/results?'
    args = urlencode({'search_query':search_query})
    while True:
        conn = urlopen(url,args)
        data = conn.read()
        conn.close()
        if 'results?' in data:
            break
    return data
```

---

As you see, I used `'results?'` in order to distinguish between valid and invalid search results.

An additional notable difference (there are many) appears at the beginning of the retrieved HTML:

- Valid results: `yt.www.masthead.sizing.runBeforeBodyIsReady(true,true,false);`
- Invalid results: `yt.www.masthead.sizing.runBeforeBodyIsReady(true,true,true);`

I have used `conn.get_code()` in order to verify that the HTTP response code is always 200.

Does anybody know of any recent changes in YouTube that might cause this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem is with `http://www.youtube.com/results?`.

This URL is being redirected to `https://www.youtube.com/results?`.

If the redirection doesn't take place, then the search results are "empty".

I was able to verify this using `conn.get_url()`:

- When it returned the original URL (the one starting with `http`), the results were invalid.
- When it returned the redirected URL (the one starting with `https`), the results were valid.